# How do I turn a PHP array into $keys and $values?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

If I have an array as `$keys => $values`, how can I get two arrays of `$keys` and `$values`?

Comment: I don't understand your question, maybe an example how it should look like?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/array_keys) and [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/array_values).

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 16):

[`array_keys`](http://docs.php.net/array_keys) and [`array_values`](http://docs.php.net/array_values) will return a numerical array of the keys/values of a given array:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
```

Or if you want a `foreach` solution:

```
$keys = array();
$values = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = $key;
    $values[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$keys   = array_keys($thearray);
$values = array_values($thearray);
```